# How to change the style of a point when clicked?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2

Sorry for this common question.
I do succeed in changing the style of a polygon when clicked, like in [this example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeature-wfs.html).

But I don't succeed with points, with the same code.

```
select = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Selection", {styleMap: 
            new OpenLayers.Style(OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["select"])
});
```

When I click on an area, an http request is send to geoserver and returns an xml with the caracterics of each points. But it does not display it.

Comment: Perhaps you need to specify first the style for points

Comment: This could be a projection issue,check if your vector layer has features after you have requested it from geoserver.